# Changing textbox background color in ssrs based on another textbox background color

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a tablix which has two columns Projects and Sale, I'm trying color the background of the textbox for Totals for Sales columns as Red if any one of the rows has their background color as Red. Is this possible using SSRS expressions ?

Comment: How does the background of a non-total cell become red?

Comment: I wouldn't do it based off the color, use the value. It may help to post some examples.